# how to change text color only in geom_label_repel() and not line color

Tags: r, ggplot2, textcolor, donut-chart, ggrepel

I'm using geom_label_repel(), and I'm trying to change the text color of my label to white but keep the line black. When I try to put the color command outside of the aes(), it makes the line and text white:

**With color argument outside of the aes()**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
 
data <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley", "Kate"),
                n = c(10, 30, 59, 1),
                prop = c(10, 30, 59, 1)) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(name)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(text_y = cumsum(prop)-prop/2)

my_colors <- c("#00A3AD", "#FF8200", "#753BBD", "#6CC24A")


 ggplot(data, aes(x = 2, y = prop, fill = name)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
    coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
    geom_label_repel(aes(y = text_y, label = paste0(n, "\n", prop, "%")), force_pull = 100, nudge_x = 1, color = "white") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors) +
    theme_void() +
    xlim(.5, 2.5)
```

[image]

But, if I put it in the aes(), it's all...orange?

**With color argument inside the aes()**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
 
data <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley", "Kate"),
                n = c(10, 30, 59, 1),
                prop = c(10, 30, 59, 1)) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(name)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(text_y = cumsum(prop)-prop/2)

my_colors <- c("#00A3AD", "#FF8200", "#753BBD", "#6CC24A")

 ggplot(data, aes(x = 2, y = prop, fill = name)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
    coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
    geom_label_repel(aes(y = text_y, label = paste0(n, "\n", prop, "%"), color = "white"), force_pull = 100, nudge_x = 1) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors) +
    theme_void() +
    xlim(.5, 2.5)
```

I'd like the white text, black line, and not have the "white" legend on the side that's present in the second one. (Also, in the second one, it makes the text in the orange label totally disappear, which isn't desirable).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out! There's another argument--`segement.color`--that sets the line (segment) color. Both `color` and `segment.color` should be set *within* the `geom_label_repel()` function but *outside* its `aes()` function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

my_colors <- c("#00A3AD", "#FF8200", "#753BBD", "#6CC24A")

        data <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley", "Kate"),
                       n = c(10, 30, 59, 1),
                       prop = c(10, 30, 59, 1)) %>%
            dplyr::arrange(desc(name)) %>%
            dplyr::mutate(text_y = cumsum(prop)-prop/2)
        
        
        ggplot(data, aes(x = 2, y = prop, fill = name)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
            coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
            geom_label_repel(aes(y = text_y, label = paste0(n, "\n", prop, "%")), force_pull = 100, nudge_x = 1,
                             color="white", segment.color="black") +
            scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors) +
            theme_void() +
            xlim(.5, 2.5)
```

[image]